# Excel Conditional formatting with Multiple cells in Merged cell range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Trying to figure out if it's possible to have conditional formatting that still highlights individual cells even if they are in a merged cell range.

Example:
[image]

In my calendar in column M I Have conditional formatting based on the name each name gets a unique color. I'd like that color to also highlight the individual cell the same color if that name appears. Right now, conditional formatting will overwrite whatever is there based on priority but I want it to show multiple colors. Is what I'm trying to do possible through conditional formatting?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking if you can display multiple conditional formatting colors in a merged range? That is not possible.

Comment: @BigBen that's exactly what I'm asking. Thanks for the info I do appreciate it! I wasn't sure or not but was thinking it wasn't.